# Jasmine does not open page

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I bet this is a dummy question, I start to work with Jasmine, but I have to write test for nonAngular page... So I start with:

```
import {by, element, browser} from "protractor";
import WebDriver = webdriver.WebDriver;
import * as webdriver from "selenium-webdriver";
describe ('COS', function() {


    beforeAll(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        console.log('-----------1');
        browser.driver.get('htpp://www.google.com/');
        console.log('-----------2');
        browser.sleep(5000);
    });
});
```

when I run it, the Chrome browser can open only URL `data:,` and nothing else. The `-----------1` and `-----------2` is shown in console properly, so the code executes. Why then the google page does not open?

Comment: Because of `htpp://www.google.com/`.

Comment: Crap... You got me